# Filter elements inside an array inside an object inside an array in Javascript returns somes values undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I am using a Japanese dictionary API, which allows me to put in a term and return a list of nouns, verbs, adverbs, and others. [This is a result of the API](https://kanji-cors-bypass.herokuapp.com/api/taberu). The API returns an array with a list of objects. Each object has its own arrays and in one of these arrays, there is the array with the information I need, like this:

```
{"data":[  
{
    "attribution": {"jmdict": true, "jmnedict": false},
    
    "senses": [
        {
            "english_definitions": [
                "sleep"
            ],

            "parts_of_speech": [
                "Noun",
                "Ichidan verb"
            ]
        },
        
        {
            "english_definitions": [
                "Sleep"
            ],
            "parts_of_speech": [
                "Ichidan verb", "intransitive verb"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

]
}

I want to filter the result to show only those results that are verbs, excluding the other results.

This is my code to do the filter:

```
verbArray = jsonData.data
let verbs2 = verbArray.filter(e => e.senses[0].parts_of_speech[0].includes('verb'));
//console.table(verbs2);
```

This code does the filter and gives me only those results that have the word verb in the string. But only if it is in position one of the array. If the term is in position two or three, will not return it

Comment: What are expected results?

Comment: In this query to the API: https://kanji-cors-bypass.herokuapp.com/api/sleep, for example, it is just filtering me the elements that have the word verb in the first position. But, those that have the word verb in the second or third position, it does not return them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
let verbs2 = verbArray.filter(e => e.senses[0].parts_of_speech.some(pos=>pos.includes('verb')));
```

if you only want to iterate all parts of speeches. The Array.prototype.some() will check all parts of speech for the term verb.

If you also want to iterate senses, you can use

```
let verbs2 = verbArray.filter(e => e.senses.some(sense=> sense.parts_of_speech.some(pos=>pos.includes('verb'))));
```

Comment: OMG! This solved my problem from weeks ago. I will study more about the .some prototype. Thank you so much!!